# Python 2: How do I limit " from file import * " ONLY import defined symbols?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

In Python2:

We all know about `__all__` to limit the imports from a module using `__init__.py` This allows you to limit what gets imported when you issue:

```
from some_module import *
```

How do you do this for all symbols in FILE (some_file.py) without generating a nasty `__all__` list?

Say you have a local `defs.py` which contains all the global variables, classes, etc you want to use thruout your code. This typically occurs when you are refactoring code and/or do not want every symbol to have a namespace prefix and/or do not want a humongo `from ... import` statement. In many cases, you **DO NOT** want to include the symbols `defs.py` imports (perhaps the import itself has a side effect you want to preserve, or you do NOT want a symbol that `defs.py` imported)

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

One answer in Python2 (likely different in Python 3) is to generate a symbol table after the imports but before your code, and at the end. Then you define `__all__` to be the difference of the two sets:

Example:

```
from some_gross_package import some_gross_symbol
import another_gross_package
from some_other_gross_package import *

# Anything above this line will be ignored.
excluded_symbols = set(dir())

from some_package_I_like import a_useful_symbol

# Now start generating symbols. Note that there will be a problem
# if you re-define a symbol from the excluded zone. Don't do that.
export_this1 = 1
export_this2 = "abc"

# Put this as the last line of your file
all_symbols = set(dir())
__all__ = list(all_symbols - excluded_symbols - {'excluded_symbols'})
```

### Caveats:

- As noted, this will break if you redefine a symbol that you actually want to export that was originally in the excluded set. But don't do that.
- Note also that this is really only for those cases in your local module where you want one `defs.py` file that contains all the various global symbols/classes (typically because you are refactoring code). But this is more of a religious issue of using `from XYZ import *`.
- It is NOT the purpose of this question to get into a religious fight about `import *` :)

Comment: why would this be different for Python 3? :D

Comment: you could additionally `del` `excluded_symbols` and `all_symbols`

Comment: Frankly, I was assuming that Python3 solved this issue. Bad on `Guido` for not addressing it.

Comment: Good point about the "del". You don't need to `del all_symbols` because `all_symbols` does not actually contain "all_symbols" (pretty ironic!) :-)

Comment: no, I mean it is an useless set after it has been used